# Слышит ли он меня, или он опять в денди-приставку/«денди»-приставку играет?

Tags: кавычки

Как правильно?

> Слышит ли он меня, или он опять в денди-приставку играет?

> Слышит ли он меня, или он опять в «денди»-приставку играет?